# How to write a loop with only if-else?

Tags: programming-languages

Someone once said to me that you can perform any programming functions with just if - else statements.

I want to know:

1. Is this statement true? (From my understanding turing-completeness depends on the ability to loop and having if/else doesn't make something turing-complete)
2. Is it possible to write a for loop with only if else statements?

How would you loop through this with only if else? ["fruit", "cars", "water"]

Comment: Really don't think this is SO material. Do you have any code that has an issue?

Comment: No, I don't have a particular programming challenge. Just trying to understand the theories behind turing completeness and what they actually mean.

Comment: Probably won't get an answer, only down votes on a question like this.

Comment: Is some form of `goto` allowed? I've only ever heard about a version of it with `if` and `goto`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Engineers can use a recursion to opposite for-while statements.
Recursion is the process of repeating items in a self-similar way.

The computation of Fibonacci numbers is a great example for understanding the
recursion (the most simple and trivial example).

`public int fibonacci(int n) {
    if (n <= 1) return n;
    else return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
}`

But recursion in most popular programming languages has some disadvantages:
(a) it's slow on big iterations and (b) uses a lot of memory for the stack
of execution.

So, yes it's possible to write a for loop with only if-else statements.

Comment: Those disadvantages are only true in languages which don't do *tail call elimination*. Granted, that's most widely used languages but, for example, Scheme has absolutely no problems using recursion for iteration and was designed around that.